# Потеря качества при сжатии

Tags: c++, bmp

Как избежать потери качества цветов при сжатии изображения? Я понимаю, что на 100 процентов без потерь не обойтись, но...

Собственно, есть изображение 512х512. Уменьшаю я его размеры в 2 раза, становится оно равным 256х256. Осуществляю сжатие по алгоритму, где исходник разбивается на квадраты 2х2 и вычисляется среднее значение.

```
// Для каждого из каналов RGB в отдельности.
R[i] = (R[o+1][p] + R[o][p+1] + R[o][p] + R[o+1][p+1])/4
```

Я имею представление, что данная формула примитивна, но она помогла мне добиться хотя бы каких-то результатов.

Comment: И... какое у вас качество теряется сверх нормы-то?

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что окно усредняющего фильтра в обозначенной формуле сдвигается не попиксельно, а на размер окна. Если так, то в этом случае также будет нарастать ошибка, помимо отбрасывания остатка при делении на 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоей формуле при целочисленном делении на 4 возникает ошибка, которую нужно или "распространять" на соседние точки, или округлять, а не просто отбрасывать дробную часть.

P.S. Для уменьшения лучше использовать фильтр Ланцоша (Lanczos), особенно если уменьшать не только в 2 раза

Comment: спасибо, прочитал про Ланцоша, также прочитал спобос который именно подходит для моих учебных целей. Перевод в формат YCbCr сжатие и обратно в RGB.